# Is it possible to include vector fields in a protobuf message to generate Rust struct?

Tags: vector, rust, protocol-buffers, proto3

I have a protobuf file used to generate types in a project. One of the types looks like:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

// ...

message myStruct {
    int32 obj_id = 1;
    string obj_code = 2;
    string obj_name = 3;
    // ... some more fields
}
// ... some more message, enum, etc ....
```

Then I can launch a tiny script that generates some Go code though `protoc-gen-go`, that gets later translated into Rust though another script using `protoc-gen-rust`.

The result is a Rust file that looks like:

```rust
// This file is generated by rust-protobuf 2.0.0. Do not edit
// @generated

// ...

pub struct myStruct {
    // message fields
    pub obj_id: i32,
    pub obj_code: ::std::string::String,
    pub obj_name: ::std::string::String,
    // ... some more fields
}
impl myStruct {
    // ... lots of constructors, getters, setters, etc
}
```

I don't want a better way to do generate the Rust types altogether, the project is massive and in prod, my job is not to rewrite/reorganize it but just to add some functionalities, for which I need some nice little vectors of flags to be added in a couple of structures.

I'd like to add some `Vec` fields in the `myStruct` struct, like those:

```rust
pub struct myClass {
    // ... some fields like obj_id etc ...

    // the fields I want to add
    bool_vec: Vec<bool>,
    bool_vec_vec: Vec<Vec<bool>>,
    // ...
}
```

Is it possible to do so using the proto-buf thing, or not? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [protobuf repeated fields](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3):

> `repeated`: this field can be repeated any number of times (including zero) in a well-formed message. The order of the repeated values will be preserved.

Like:

```
message bool_vec{
    repeated bool element = 1;
}
message bool_vec_vec{
    repeated bool_vec element = 1;
}
message myStruct {
    ...
    bool_vec v = 100;
    bool_vec_vec vv = 101;
    ...
}
```

The [documentation of `RepeatedField`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedField) from the protobuf C++ library (which represents repeated fields like the repeated `bool` here)  shows that it has what we would expect from vectors: access by index and iterators. Your generated code will also have access by index and add/remove last methods.